# Powershell conditions for passed parameter

Tags: powershell, if-statement, parameters

I am passing a hashtable that looks like that

```
$table = @{
   Enabled = $true
   Name = $Name
}
```

I have a function which gets this object and creates an item.
One of the Function's parameter is the Not Mandatory $Enabled status.

I want to create a condition that only in case the $Enabled parameter is passed to the function to accept it's content $true/$false. in other words, if I pass

```
$table=@{
  Name = $Name
}
```

it should create the object as a predefined value for Enabled - either true or false.

The condition

```
if($Enabled){
  do something
}
```

is executed either when the parameter is passed, or when it's set to true (which are desired scenarios).
However, if it's set to $false (another desired scenario), it won't get into it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like the issue is with the function parameter declarations.

Comment: both of your "hashtables" are actually _scriptblocks_.  this >>> `$table.GetType().Name` <<< gives this >>> `ScriptBlock` <<<

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the @ infront of the curly braces. They are hashtables, it's just that I didn't copy the exact code here, but had to type it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
I set a ParameterSetName for that variable

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Enabled")]
[bool]$Enabled
```

Then inside the function the condition would look like:

```
if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Enabled') {
    $object.add('Enabled',$Enabled)
}
```